# How to put inner fading like shadow in edittext?

Tags: android, android-layout, layer-list

I am trying to create a fading like shadow inside the inner boundary of an EditText. Here is what i have achieved :-
[image]

These xml's I have used for both EditText, but let's focus on the above only :-

**username_shape.xml**

```
<!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#d8d8d8" />

        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- White Top color -->
<item
    android:left="3px"
    android:right="3px"
    android:top="3px">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**password_shape.xml**

```
    <!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#d8d8d8" />

            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- White Top color -->
    <item android:bottom="3px"
        android:left="3px"
        android:right="3px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I want to achieve something like in the image below. Please notice the inner shadow(**Don't mind the blue background)**. It is fading sort of. This is what i want to achieve.
[image]

Comment: give padding to layout in which your edittext included

Comment: How will that create a faded shadow ? This won't work

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is nearly a year old, I am looking for something similar and still cannot find an example of a 'fading' shadow. The closest I have come to is apply a gradient for the item being used for the shadow, something like

```
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
        android:startColor="#ef4444"
        android:endColor="#992f2f"
        android:angle="270" />

        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I know this still does not achieve the result you are looking for, but someone might get inspired of how to solve using the gradient property.